# Problem with jQuery accordion and cookies

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a jQuery accordion from [this](http://www.i-marco.nl/weblog/jquery-accordion-menu-redux2/) site and edited for my purposes, but the accordion only works in Firefox (not Safari or Chrome) and the cookies aren't being set correctly.

This is the jQuery:

```
            function initMenus() {
                $('#sidebar .letter_index').hide();
                $.each($('#sidebar .letter_index'), function() {
                    var cookie = $.cookie(this.id);
                    if (cookie === null || String(cookie).length < 1) {
                        $('#sidebar .letter_index:first').show();
                    }   else {
                        $('#' + this.id + ' .' + cookie).next().show();
                    }
                });
                $('#sidebar .letter_head').click(function() {
                    var checkElement = $(this).next();
                    var parent = this.parentNode.parentNode.id;

                    if ((checkElement.is('.letter_index')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                        $('#' + parent + ' .letter_index:visible').slideUp('normal');
                            if ((String(parent).length > 0) && (String(this.className).length > 0)) {
                                // not working
                                $.cookie(parent, this.className);
                            }
                        checkElement.slideDown('normal');
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                );
            }
            $(document).ready(function() {initMenus();});
```

This is how my HTML looks (sample item):

```
            <div id="sidebar">
      <h2 class="letter_head"><a href="#" class="ABC">ABC</h2>
      <ul class="letter_index">
        <li>Abc</li>
        <li>Bcd</li>
      </ul>
            </div>
```

I can't find the problem why the script won't work in Safari and Chrome.

I also don't know how to tell it to use the class of the `a` inside the `h2` as the cookie value. (Currently the cookie is set as `$.cookie(parent, this.className);`, which produces cookies with the name `container` (the div above #sidebar) and the value `letter_head`. It needs to be something like 'sidebar' and 'ABC', 'DEF' and so on.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n7dSF/) for you. I had to rewrite a bunch of the code because the original script was written to work with multiple accordions, but I am going to assume you only want to use this script for one. Anyway, here is the HTML I used:

```
<div id="container">  
 <div id="sidebar">

  <h2 class="letter_head"><a href="#" class="ABC1">ABC1</a></h2>
  <ul class="letter_index">
   <li>Abc1</li>
   <li>Bcd1</li>
  </ul>

  <h2 class="letter_head"><a href="#" class="ABC2">ABC2</a></h2>
  <ul class="letter_index">
   <li>Abc2</li>
   <li>Bcd2</li>
  </ul>

  <h2 class="letter_head"><a href="#" class="ABC3">ABC3</a></h2>
  <ul class="letter_index">
   <li>Abc3</li>
   <li>Bcd3</li>
  </ul>

 </div>  
</div>
```

Script:

```
function initMenus() {
 var sidebar = $('#sidebar');
 sidebar.find('ul.letter_index').hide();
 var cookie = $.cookie( sidebar.attr('id') );
 if (cookie === null || String(cookie).length < 1) {
  sidebar.find('.letter_index:first').show();
 } else {
  sidebar.find(('h2 > a.' + cookie)).parent().next().show();
 }

 sidebar.find('h2.letter_head').click(function(){
  var checkElement = $(this).next();
  if ((checkElement.is('.letter_index')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
   sidebar.find('.letter_index:visible').slideUp('normal');
   var headClassName = $(this).find('a').attr('class').trim();
   if (headClassName.length > 0) {
    $.cookie( sidebar.attr('id'), headClassName );
   }
   checkElement.slideDown('normal');
   return false;
  }
 });
}
$(document).ready(function() {initMenus();});
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! :) The cookies work perfectly now, however the accordion is still not working in Chrome, Opera or Safari. Edit: I just noticed that the fiddle works, but my script not. The Problem must be somewhere in my PHP which generates the menu, so I'm looking into that :)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply; I now included url rewriting like /en/about/ etc. into my site and the menu doesn't work anymore because the cookies are set for the specific paths. How can I set the cookie without taking the path into consideration, so the menu would work again across the entire site?

Comment: Hi Rayne! Try changing this line `$.cookie( sidebar.attr('id'), headClassName );` to this `$.cookie( sidebar.attr('id'), headClassName, { path: '/' });`